# Lipschitz continuity result for a function defined on compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$ where both $X,Y$ are compact sets. If $f$ is continuous then can I conclude that it is also Lipschitz continuous?

Is this result true? I cannot seem to find a counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. I claim that $f$ is continuous, but not Lipschitz. Suppose that there exists $C$ such that for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|.$$ Then letting $y=0$ we have for all $x>0$, $$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\leq C.$$ But since $1/\sqrt{x}$ is unbounded as $x\to 0$, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Okay, many thanks. Does local Lipschitz property hold then? @Alex S

Comment: @user440024 Reread the definition of locally Lipchitz and consider the case $x=0$.